# Debugging Spring autowiring failure for ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, debugging, autowired, applicationcontext

I am currently in Spring Hell in trying to determine why an @Autowired instance of ApplicationContext is not being injected or is null in the target class for some JUnit tests. The class referencing the ApplicationContext variable is annotated as a @Component and other @Component classes in the same package are being wired properly with different variables. I have tried adding log4j debugging but I end up with a ridiculous amount of output that is not even possible to wade through.

I am wondering if anyone can point me in the direction of the Spring package and classes that do the autoscanning so that I can try to step through the Spring code and see why the class is silently ignored. I have not found a good entry point to start the debugging effort and I am really tired of trial and error in trying to resolve this.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Post some code. The spring stuff is pretty bullet proof. You are probably making some more or less obvious mistake.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a way to debug, not suggestions on which spells to cast with Spring to make the beast happy. All my other classes have the same format and are working, but the ApplicationContext injection is simply not happening.

Comment: Just to check yourself try implementing the ApplicationContextAware interface in your chess.

Comment: I have done that and it does not get called either. Hence why I am looking at direct debugging the scanning. Basically classes A and B in the same package are both annotated as Component and both used Autowired, but only the one without the ApplicationContext variable gets its value.

Comment: Any post that says "Spring hell" gets +1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a workaround and not a complete answer as I am still looking for a way to debug autoscanning. However, for others who run into this, what I ended up doing is retaining my ApplicationContext in a static variable within the class that later needs it.

While playing around and debugging, I noticed that setApplicationContext from the ApplicationContextAware interface would get called but only at the start of my JUnit tests so I retained it for later use. This is a bit of kludge, but barring a good solution, this is what I have chosen go with for now. We'll see if it bites me later.